# I want to add data from data base every thing is going true .... data is not stored in array, my code is here

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

I want to select data from data base in array (imagearray) cursor is going through dictonary but data is not stored in array....

```
-(void)getdataFromDatabase
{
    NSString *sqlQueryString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT imageName,imageDetail,Date_Time FROM Image_Table"];
    const char *sql=[sqlQueryString UTF8String];

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(delegate.DVCRS, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *dicRD = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dicRD setValue:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)] forKey:@"imageName"];
            [dicRD setValue:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)] forKey:@"imageDetail"];
            [dicRD setValue:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)] forKey:@"Date_Time"];
            [imagearray addObject:dicRD];
            [imagenamearray addObject:dicRD];
        }
        NSLog(@"Main Object data  is %d",[imagearray count]);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR getdata %s",(char *)sqlite3_errmsg(delegate.DVCRS));
    }
    sqlite3_reset(statement);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
```

Comment: Did you alloc+init the arrays? Otherwise `imagearray` is `nil` and `addObject:` puts the object into ... nothing.

Comment: yaa , i have but it is not working properly,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change  your code inside if

```
     while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                NSMutableDictionary *dicRD = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
                [dicRD setValue:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)] forKey:@"imageName"];
                [dicRD setValue:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)] forKey:@"imageDetail"];
                [dicRD setValue:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)] forKey:@"Date_Time"];
NSArarry *imagearray=[NSArray alloc]init;
                [imagearray addObject:dicRD];
                [imagenamearray addObject:dicRD];
            }
            NSLog(@"Main Object data  is %d",[imagearray count]);
```

Answer (score 0):

My first advice is you should always differentiate local variables and attributes. Either by using and underscore as prefix (which is now done by default) or by using the properties instead (self.propertyName). When you can you should prefer the `self.` method.

For your example code, we don't know where imagearray and imagenamearray are initialized.

And second advice put first words letters in uppercase : imageArray & imageNameArray. It's more easy to read. And keep consistency (imageName vs Date_Time) or use constants.

Third and last advice you can use now objective-C 2.0 syntax for dictionaries and arrays.

So :

```
if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(delegate.DVCRS, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSMutableArray *imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *imageNameArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSMutableDictionary *dicRD = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            dicRD[@"imageName"] = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            dicRD[@"imageDetail"] = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            dicRD[@"dateTime"] = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            [imagearray addObject:dicRD];
            [imagenamearray addObject:dicRD];
        }
        NSLog(@"Main Object data  is %d",[imagearray count]);
    }
```

Or even better :

```
        while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSDictionary *dicRD = @{
            "imageName"   : [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)],
            "imageDetail" : [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)],
            "dateTime"    : [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)]};
            [imagearray addObject:dicRD];
            [imagenamearray addObject:dicRD];
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Inititalize your array 'imagearray' and 'imagenamearray' if not initialized before. It will be set to nil by default. Intitialize before starting while loop.